# Revit API: NewFamilyDocument - where to get the template?

Tags: revit-api

My code `doc.Application.NewFamilyDocument(template_path);` requires a path to a Revit family template. Currently we made a copy of, say "Metric Mass.rft" and redistribute this.
Is there a way to either/or

- get the default path for these family templates
- create a family document without the template

instead?

Answer (score 0):

The default library paths are accessible via the [`GetLibraryPaths` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/4782f03c-9661-3bb5-0156-03ef96a2c69b.htm). For examples of using it, please refer to the Revit SDK samples, e.g., RoutingPreferenceTools, UIAPI, RevitCommands, and The Building Coder samples external command `CmdLibraryPaths`, described in the article on [Library Paths](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/08/library-paths.html)
.

Comment: But the sub-folders are named differently for each language. So I have trouble finding "Metric Mass.rtf" on a German operating system.

Comment: If it is still named `Metric Mass.rtf`, you can simply use the .NET and Windows API functionality to search recursively through all the folders for the matching filename. If the name varies between languages, you will have to solve that. Maybe maintain a table of translations?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from R17 you can create new doc like this

```
unitSys_metric = UnitSystem.Metric
newDoc = app.NewProjectDocument(unitSys_metric)
```

Have a good day! :)